# MPU6050 Gyro rotaion always around Y axis

Tags: imu, gyroscope, accelerometer, rotation

I am using an MPU6050 IMU. I did a small experiment having Z-axis pointing upwards.
1. Rotate 90deg around Z-axis (yaw) and back to the original position
2. Rotate 90deg around X-axis (roll) and back to the original position

The issue is that accel data is perfect and I could see data as expected. But, the gyro data shows rotation only around Y-axis. I am a bit confused. Is this expected and need some post-processing to get the Euler angles. OR is there an issue, Please explain.

[image]

Accel Data
[image]

Comment: are you certain that you are reading the gyro module output correctly?

Comment: Yes. The final result of the rotation angle is perfect. But, the only issue is that the Y-axis has both the values from that of the Z and X-axis. I would be certain that there is a mismatch in the axis if all 3 rotations were distributed among diff axes. But single-axis giving 2 values is misleading. And I am reading accel and gyro data in a single chunk. Accel values look fine.